# Why doesn't ssh localhost sh -c 'echo "$0"' arg0 output anything?

Tags: shell, ssh

Similar to [Why doesn't echo called as /bin/sh -c echo foo output anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253422/why-doesnt-echo-called-as-bin-sh-c-echo-foo-output-anything) but using `ssh`.

Why doesn't this output anything:

```
ssh localhost sh -c 'echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But if I change it to

```
ssh localhost sh -c 'true; echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3
# Output is
0=bash 1= arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I see behavior that implies the echo command is being run but the way the variable substitution is working is not as expected.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253424/119816

#### Running without ssh works as expected

Same as above but removing the ssh command

```
sh -c 'echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3
# Output is
0=arg1 1=arg2

# Adding true gives same output
sh -c 'true; echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3
0=arg1 1=arg2
```

#### I'm trying copy a root accessible file from one system to another

I'm trying to get an ssh command working to copy a root file to another system.  The command I'm trying is:

```
file=/etc/hosts
set -x
ssh host1 sudo cat $file | ssh host2 sudo sh -c 'exec cat "$0"' $file
# Output is
+ ssh host2 sudo sh -c 'exec cat > "$0"' /etc/hosts
+ ssh host1 sudo cat /etc/hosts
bash: : No such file or directory
```

This looks OK to me, and I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot.

#### My solution

My solution is to fall back to what I've used before

```
ssh host1 sudo cat $file | ssh host2 sudo tee $file > /dev/null
```

The above works.

#### Searching for a solution

I've had this problem and asked the question:

- [Does Unix have a command to read from stdin and write to a file (like tee without sending output to stdout)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712933/does-unix-have-a-command-to-read-from-stdin-and-write-to-a-file-like-tee-withou)

Other's have had problems/questions with `sh -c` command:

- [Why doesn't echo called as /bin/sh -c echo foo output anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253422/why-doesnt-echo-called-as-bin-sh-c-echo-foo-output-anything)

But there must be a subtlety that occurs when using ssh which results in an additional shell evaluation.

Comment: quoting is wrong for what SSH is running... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715686/ssh-host-bash-c-cmd-why-is-first-line-of-output-lost https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590209/why-do-ls-parameters-seem-to-not-work-in-commands-run-via-ssh-host-bash-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do ls parameters seem to not work in commands run via ssh host bash -c?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590209/why-do-ls-parameters-seem-to-not-work-in-commands-run-via-ssh-host-bash-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `-v` to your `ssh` command, it will show you what it's doing:

```
debug1: Sending command: sh -c echo "0=$0 1=$1" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Sure enough, if we run that `sh` command locally, we just get an empty line of output, because `sh` is running `echo` and `"0=$0 1=$1"` becomes the zeroth argument.

When we prepend `true;`, this happens:

```
debug1: Sending command: sh -c true; echo "0=$0 1=$1" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now `sh` just runs `true`.  And then `echo` outputs its arguments:

```
0=bash 1= arg1 arg2 arg3
```

What you probably want is to run `sh -c 'echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3` on the far side.  You'll need to quote that whole command so it's received intact by the remote shell:

```bash
ssh localhost "sh -c 'echo \"0=\$0 1=\$1\"' arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

Output:

```
0=arg1 1=arg2
```

If you have GNU `printf` (on the local side), you could make this more readable by using it to format the command string suitably for the far end:

```bash
command='echo "0=$0 1=$1"'
ssh localhost "sh -c $(printf %q "$command") arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

Comment: Pro Tip: Adding `-v` option.  I use it all the time to debug ssh credential issues, but never thought to use it for debugging shell commands.

Answer (score 11):

It's the same issue as in your referenced question. The local shell removes a layer of quotes. Here's what's happening

Initial code

```
ssh localhost sh -c 'echo "0=$0 1=$1"' arg1 arg2 arg3
```

After local shell expansion but before command execution

```
ssh localhost sh -c echo "0=$0 1=$1" arg1 arg2 arg3
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ a single token
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ passed to the remote shell
```

In the remote shell after shell expansion but before execution

```
sh -c echo 0= 1= arg1 arg2 arg3
#          ^^^^^ a single token
#     ^^^^ argument for -c
```

The `echo` gets bound to the `sh -c` as the command to execute and the remainder are arguments.

You should get a blank line.

Personally, I learned that `ssh` passed its args directly to the remote shell, and that's where it was executed. As a result I tend to write `ssh` commands like this, which reminds me that the `some command line…` part will be passed verbatim to a remote shell for execution *as if I'd typed it directly*:

```
ssh remoteHost 'some command line…'
```

(Wrap the line in single quotes to avoid local evaluation, or use double quotes to interpolate local variables.)

---

You then say that actually you're trying to get an ssh command working to copy a root file to another system

```
file=/etc/hosts
ssh -n host1 "scp -p '$file' host2:'/path/to/destination'"
```

Or, since the file name is safe, and assuming you have root equivalence between the local client and `host1`, and from `host1` to `host2`:

```
ssh -n root@host1 scp -p /etc/hosts host2:/etc/hosts
```

With a modern `scp` that in turn can be simplified further:

```
scp -OR -p root@host1:/etc/hosts root@host2:/etc/
```

Comment: obvious followup: why the heck does ssh concatenate all the arguments and parse them again? It already has the separate arguments - this is annoying behaviour.

Comment: To be honest I'd never considered that. I learned that `ssh` passed its args to the remote shell, and that's where it was executed. As a result I tend to write `ssh remoteHost 'some command line…'`, which reminds me that the `some command line…` part will be passed verbatim to a remote shell for execution _as if I'd typed it directly_. (Wrap the line in single quotes to avoid local evaluation, or use double quotes to interpolate local variables.) I'll update my question to include this.

Comment: @user253751 ssh doesn't parse the arguments again, it passes them to a shell on the remote system and *that* parses them. If the remote command wasn't parsed by a remote shell, you couldn't use any shell features like redirects, wildcards, or compound commands (multiple commands separated by `;`, `||`, `&&`, or `if` or `while` or ...). It looks to me like the real problem here is that you've added a *third* shell (and a third layer of parsing) by using `sh -c`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson why should one expect to be able to use shell features in a command executed by ssh? by default they would be executed by the local shell, and if you want a remote shell, then you ask for one.

Comment: @user253751 `ssh` _does_ ask for a remote shell. By definition

Comment: @user253751 To be fair "ssh" stands for "secure shell"

Comment: @user253751, the remote system might implement some restrictions through the choice of the user's shell, including things like having a restricted or totally customized shell, or even preventing logins by having something like `/bin/false` as the shell. That's useful and straightforward behaviour and means restrictions like that don't need to be implemented in multiple places (like the SSH server configuration in addition to the user's `passwd` entry). I wouldn't be surprised if there were compatibility issues with earlier tools like rsh too, but I don't really know about those.

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, that's what it stands for, but the intent is that it's the secure replacement for the previous `rsh`, which stands for "remote shell". They could have called it `srsh` to be explicit, but they chose a shorter name.

Comment: @user253751 *why the heck does ssh concatenate all the arguments?*. So that you can write simple commands more easily, e.g. `ssh hostname cp foo bar` instead of `ssh hostname 'cp foo bar'`

Comment: ssh _passes_ the arguments as a single token. concatenation would be: **sh-c'echo"0=$01=$2"'arg1arg2arg3** . perhaps i'm splitting hair here, but I would not call what ssh is doing concatenation.

Comment: In my case I could not use root directly to login, this was not permitted.  All root actions had to be initiated via sudo after logging in as a "non root" user.  So the statement "assuming you have root equivalence" and corresponding use of `root@host1:/etc/hosts` could not be used.  Also it took me a little while to understand your answer, but overall it was **very informative**.  Thanks and Best Wishes.